# Error message with a method in app delegate

Tags: ios, appdelegate

[image]

What am I missing? I keep getting these error messages.

New pic

[image]

Comment: Doesn't seem to be an import problem. Do I need to declare anything?

Comment: Only use the [tag:xcode] tag for questions about the IDE itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the framework:

Click on your project title

[image: Project Button]

Scroll down to Linked Frameworks and Libraries

[image: Linked Frameworks and Libraries]

Click The Plus (+)

Find The Framework You Want To Add. You May Have To Choose Add Other and Then Find The .Framework file elsewhere on your computer.

Then Click Add

Comment: How do I link framework. The class is defined in parse.h

Comment: See Above. I edited it.